# useContext not working with npm workspace

Tags: reactjs, react-context, npm-workspaces

My project using npm workspace.

```
.
├── package.json
└── packages
   ├── app
   │  ├── application1
   │  │  └── package.json
   │  └── application2
   │     └── package.json
   └── modules
      └── package.json
```

`app` directory contains the React application, and `modules` package contains Component and Custom Hooks commonly used by each application.

Context defined on the application does not work when trying to use it in a Custom Hook on the modules package.
The default value of `createContext` is always returned.

`useContext` does not work on external packages?

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: I suppose you defined a `Provider` for your context among the ancestors of the component where you `useContext`?

Comment: @Valentin Yes, so `useContext` called from custom hook defined on `application` is working well.